# Reuse of null class

Tags: c#, webkit.net

Look at the following codes

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class myprogram : Form
{
    public myprogram()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    WebKitBrowser wb1 = new WebKitBrowser();



     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        wb1.Navigate("site.com");
        timer2.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Enabled = false;
        wb1=null;    
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }      
}
}
```

To empty RAM every time, wb1 must be null. But then it gets null and no longer hits and says it has already been null. So how can I get null in timer2 and then Navigate in timer1?

Comment: What is your interval for `timer1` and `timer2`? Why are you using timers at all? What is your underlying problem - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I would release resource After each Navigate

Comment: I asked three questions (you answered one at best). Also please explain why you are using `WebKitBrowser` at all. Let's say I commented out the `WebKitBrowser` code. What problem would that cause your end users?

Comment: I'd suggest commenting out the line `wb1=null;`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `wb1 = new WebKitBrowser();` to timer1_Tick